# Кнопка "показать"

Tags: jquery

Как сделать кнопку «показать», такую, чтобы при ее нажатии показывался бы контент, а сама кнопка бы пропадала.

Принцип такой: нажимаешь на кнопку «показать» и кнопка меняется на контент, без кнопки «скрыть».

Comment: для скрытия используется метод `hide()` для показа - `show()`

Comment: Вам сюда: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0  и конкретно: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: Я все понимаю но кнопка остается, а мне нужно чтоб кнопка Показать пропала

Comment: так? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/4tLcno6v/

Comment: чтобы кнопка пропала, примените к ней метод _hide_, чтобы показать "содержимое" - примените к нему метод _show_.